# 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports

Tags: k3s

### while redeploy it stucks as following but while scaling (0,1) deployment it work,
White might be the cause

kubectl describe pod backendnew-6f9cbc5fb-v2nbc

Name:           backendnew-6f9cbc5fb-v2nbc

Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           
Labels:         pod-template-hash=6f9cbc5fb
                workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector=deployment-default-backendnew

Annotations:    cattle.io/timestamp: 2021-09-27T11:55:38Z
                field.cattle.io/ports:
                  [[{"containerPort":7080,"dnsName":"backendnew-nodeport","hostPort":7080,"kind":"NodePort","name":"port","protocol":"TCP","sourcePort":7080...
                field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: [{"addresses":["192.168.178.13"],"nodeId":"c-jq2bh:machine-7g9vs","port":7080,"protocol":"TCP"}]
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/backendnew-6f9cbc5fb
Containers:
  backendnew:
    Image:      kub-repo.f1soft.com/fonepay/grpay-admin:8
    Port:       7080/TCP
    Host Port:  7080/TCP
    Environment:
      server.port:             7080
      spring.profiles.active:  PROD
    Mounts:
      /app/config from vol1 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-rmt6g (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  vol1:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      configoriginal
    Optional:  false
  default-token-rmt6g:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-rmt6g
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling    default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.
  Warning  FailedScheduling    default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.

Comment: kubectl get node
NAME                    STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
localhost.localdomain   Ready    master   197d   v1.18.9+k3s1